# How to flatten interface type in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Given this type in Typescript

```
type MyType = {
    name: string;
    gender?: "male" | "female";
    section: {
        a: string;
        b: string;
    };
}
```

Hot to transform the type into flatted version like so?

```
{
    name: string;
    gender?: "male" | "female";
    "section.a": string;
    "section.b": string;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "flatten"?

Comment: `section.a` is not a valid key

Comment: @thedude it can be, if you enclose it in quotes `"section.b": string` (not that I say this is good practice!)

Comment: So still: What's your actual question. Seems like you "flattened" it already ...

Comment: @derpirscher By flatten I mean transfrom the type and use it as Flatten<MyType>.

Comment: Sorry for the confustion

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing the point, but surely any code doing the flattening will only occur at run time, skipping the compile time checks that make interfaces so useful?

Comment: I needed to only flatten the type but not on the object. My purpose here is to create the type suggestion while using in the editor.

Comment: Yes, This exactly will be the answer with a bit of modification. Thanks a ton.